# PowerShell Global Variable

Tags: function, shell, powershell, module

I'm trying to create a Function on my module that will create a PsSession and to import it to my console. The script block itself is ok, but after running the cmdlet, I cannot import the PsSession although the function imports it.

```
Function ConnectTo-Office365 {
[cmdletbinding()]

$365Credential = Get-Credential -Message "Office365 Credentials";
$365Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $365Credential -Authentication  Basic -AllowRedirection;
Import-PSSession $365Session}
```

I've read on Global Variables but could not understand how to use it to my purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: Does using $Global:365Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $365Credential -Authentication  Basic -AllowRedirection;
Import-PSSession $365Session} have any affect on your function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import-PsSession not available after function completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013012/import-pssession-not-available-after-function-completes)

Comment: Using $Global:Sessin did get me the session variable!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a global variable.

```
Function ConnectTo-Office365 {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param (
    $Credential = (Get-Credential -Message "Office365 Credentials")
  )

  $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $Credential -Authentication  Basic -AllowRedirection

  Return $Session
}

PS> Import-PSSession (ConnectTo-Office365)

PS> Import-PSSession (ConnectTo-Office356 -Credential $Cred)
```